# Sending hidden request to oAuth

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I wanted to show GA data to each one client on my website. Each one of them has create own GA profile, I store in database `profile_id`.

Credentials to GA data are my personal, the same for all profiles, all profiles are in my account. For settings oAuth I used this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/google-analytics-api/.

Clients don´t know my credentials and I don´t want to create them permissions to see the stats. I need the only login into my website (login data are *URL|password*). After they logged into the client section, I select from database their profile ID and need to show them their stats (without showing Google login dialog). I´d like to pass my credentials directly somewhere in the PHP script.

So, question is:
**Is possible to show GA data using oAuth directly without showing Google login dialog? To login in app´s backend?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you do the OAuth 2 flow correctly, you will get an access token. Once you have that access token you can use it to query any Google Analytics view (previously called profile) to which you have access.

To do the query, simply append the access token as a query parameter when making your request to the Core Reporting API. This reference shows how to add the access token to the request:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#q_summary

If you don't want to build the charting yourself, you should also look into using the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/). You can use the Embed API's `serverAuth` option when authorizing to avoid having to have your users log in with their Google accounts:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#auth

Comment: Thanks. Can you please be a little bit more specific? In http://www.sitepoint.com/google-analytics-api/#highlighter_898546, do I need there lines 3-40, I mean they initialize the login screen, or not? I´m not sure exactly how and where to append the access token. Thanks.

Comment: Try: 1) Look up [this report](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A73084290&dimensions=ga%3Adate&metrics=ga%3Asessions&start-date=2014-10-19&end-date=2014-11-02) and authorize to get a list of your accounts 2) Click on "Query URI" button (the globe) and notice how it's just a big long URL 3) Paste that URL into a new tab, notice the error "login required" 4) append a valid access token to the end of the URL, e.g. `&access_token=XXXX` and it will work. Easiest way to get a valid access token is using the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).